# If statement in access

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba

```
If IsNull(CusID) Or IsNull(Me.CusID) Then
    Beep
    MsgBox "Specify a Customer or enter CustomerID to proceed", vbCritical
    CusID.SetFocus
End If

If IsNull(paymenttype) Or IsNull(Me.paymenttype) Then
    Beep
    MsgBox "Please specify payment type", vbCritical
    paymenttype.SetFocus
End If

If IsNull(payment) Or IsNull(Me.payment) Then
    Beep
    MsgBox "Please enter any amount to proceed payment.", vbCritical
    payment.SetFocus
End If
```

Please if someone help me to put these if statement into a if else....something to check step by step the action of if statement. This is from a form name 'payment' then i need to make sure that none of this text boxes are null or empty before proceed payment....please help

Comment: You may want to add the name of the _language_ you're coding in..

Comment: You might not actually want to do that. As you have it written, each field will be validated every time. If you go with an `ElseIf`, then if the `CusID` is null, then the other fields won't be validated until the next time the code is run. (Assuming `CusId` was corrected prior to that.) i guess it depends on what you think the better UX would be.

Comment: Thank you RubberDuck and stefan.....without all your help I won't able to make it right....I hope that you help again in any matters in the future....

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like the following?:

```
If IsNull(CusID) Or IsNull(Me.CusID) Then
  Beep
  MsgBox "Specify a Customer or enter CustomerID to proceed", vbCritical
  CusID.SetFocus

ElseIf IsNull(paymenttype) Or IsNull(Me.paymenttype) Then
  Beep
  MsgBox "Please specify payment type", vbCritical
  paymenttype.SetFocus

ElseIf IsNull(payment) Or IsNull(Me.payment) Then
  Beep
  MsgBox "Please enter any amount to proceed payment.", vbCritical
  payment.SetFocus

End If
```

I added just "Else" before "If" along the [MS ACCESS: IF-THEN-ELSE STATEMENT](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/if_then.php)

Comment: Edited your code, as there was a syntactic error. It is **ElseIf** not **Else *<space>* If**

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake. Thank you for your correcting!

Comment: my pleasure! Anyway, if your problem is solved, I recommend to close the question :)